# Need to create a histogram in Python for a corpus

Tags: python, nltk, dictionary

```
import nltk
from nltk.book import *
from nltk.corpus import brown
corpus_text = brown.words()
word_freq = FreqDist(corpus_text)
word_hist = dict()

for k,v in word_freq.iteritems():
   if key in word_hist:
      word_hist[v] = word_hist[v] + 1
   else:
      word_hist[v] = 1 

print word_hist.viewkeys()
print word_hist.viewvalues()
```

I'm making a mistake at the dictionary handling here. Need to create a dictionary that has
it's keys as the words from the freqdict and the values as the number of the corresponding word. how do I perform this increment?

I'm certain that

```
      word_hist[v] = word_hist[v] + 1
   else:
      word_hist[v] = 1
```

has a bug.

Comment: looks like m getting a ubuntu bug.. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hist.py", line 12, in <module>
    word_hist[v] = word_hist[v] + 1
KeyError: 62713

Comment: Unlikely. You rather use your variables in the wrong way. See my edited answer - or use S.Lott's `defaultdict()` version. And don't forget to accept one of these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. It seems you are replacing the `word_hist` dict with one of its values (plus 1). Try

```
word_hist[v] = word_hist[v] + 1
```

or even better

```
word_hist[v] += 1
```

instead.

EDIT: There is another bug:

```
for k,v in word_freq.iteritems():
   if key in word_hist:
      word_hist[v] = word_hist[v] + 1
   else:
      word_hist[v] = 1
```

makes no sense. `key` is tested for presence in `word_hist`, but then `v` is used.

I don't know what `key` is, but either use `k` or `v` for both.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
word_hist = defaultdict(int)

for k,v in word_freq.iteritems():
    word_hist[v] +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

that definitely has a bug, but so does the previous line.

```
if key in word_hist:
      word_hist[v] = word_hist[v] + 1
   else:
      word_hist[v] = 1
```

should be

```
if k in word_hist:
    word_hist[k] = word_hist[k] + 1
else:
    word_hist[k] = 1
```

you don't need to take v from the word_freq.